# Removing a Wordpress Action from theme via plugin

Tags: wordpress

Im adding a copyright link in footer of a theme using the

```
function copy() {
echo '<div class="copyright"><a href="http://domain/" title="Title">Text</a></div>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'copy');
```

and trying to remove it writing a simple plugin like this one:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Link Remover
Plugin URI: http://domain/
Version: 1.0
Author: authorname
Description: Plugin description
*/
remove_action('wp_footer', 'copy');
?>
```

but it doesnt remove in this way is there any other method to do this?

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function remove_copyright()
{
    remove_action('wp_footer', 'copy');
}
add_action('init','remove_copyright', 15);
```

Comment: ohh sorry it should be `remove_action('wp_footer', 'copy');` but stil not removing

Comment: @Gazi then `add_action` is ran after `remove_action`. Where are you calling them?

Comment: So the add action is in theme files, but as you see Im trying to remove it using a plugin, without removing the code from theme,I would like to understand the logic how to remove_action using a plugin without removing the code from theme

Comment: @Gazi inside the theme, is `add_action` wrapped inside some function that is hooked to some other action?

Comment: No its same like the first code in my question,`function copy() {
echo '<div class="copyright"><a href="http://domain/" title="Title">Text</a></div>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'copy');` this is the working function in theme but I want to deactivate the function via a plugin, Im sorry for my bad explantion :)

Comment: @Gazi Try latest edit of my answer. That should do it then.

Comment: Tried but didnt remove the link however thanks for your responses

Comment: changed your code to `add_action('init','remove_copyright', 15);` and worked fine thankyou for your help